# KnockoutJS Grouping ObservableArray entries by child Property array

Tags: knockout.js

I've been pondering the best way to achieve this outcome for some time and have had success really tweaking my display templates and JS, but it's not scalable.

I have an observableArray, ContentGrid[], each item in the array has multiple objects including an object Taxonomies{} which contains objects Product & Docs. Both Product and Docs contain an array of items matching their classification, for example Product contains [ProductA] and Docs:[Photos].

I'd like to be able to group results by Product A, Product B, Product C, etc, however, I can't seem to find the right syntax to make this possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `pureComputed` that loops over the `ContentGrid` array to create a group per unique product.

The example below shows:

- Create a `Map` to hold the groups. Its *keys* refer to a *product* and its *values* will be parts of your grid (i.e. partial `ContentGrid`s)
- Iterate over the rows of the grid using `for ... of`
- Iterate over all products in the row using `for ... of`
- Ensure there's an empty array (= content grid) in the `Map`
- Ensure this row gets logged in this product's group

To make it easier to render the groups to the UI, I transform the `Map` instance in to an array of viewmodels. Each group gets a model with a

- `title` referring to the product
- `rows` referring to the parts of the grid that matched this product.

As you can see this grouping will duplicate rows that have multiple products. If you want to implement a different grouping strategy, you'll likely want to update the inner loop.

```js
const contentGrid = ko.observableArray([
  { id: "Grid row 1", taxonomies: { product: [{ id: "Product C" }] } },
  { id: "Grid row 2", taxonomies: { product: [{ id: "Product B" }] } },
  { id: "Grid row 3", taxonomies: { product: [{ id: "Product A" }] } },
  { id: "Grid row 4", taxonomies: { product: [{ id: "Product A" }, { id: "Product B" }] } },
  { id: "Grid row 5", taxonomies: { product: [{ id: "Product A" }, { id: "Product B" }, { id: "Product C" }] } }
]);

// A computed list of all rows
const rowsByProduct = ko.pureComputed(() => {
  const rowsByProductId = new Map();
  
  for (const contentRow of contentGrid()) {
    for (const product of contentRow.taxonomies.product) {
      if (!rowsByProductId.has(product.id)) {
        rowsByProductId.set(product.id, []);  
      }
      
      // Add the content row for this product
      rowsByProductId.get(product.id).push(contentRow);
    }
  }

  // Format our map's entries to viewmodels
  return Array
    .from(rowsByProductId.keys())
    .sort()
    .map(productId => ({
      title: productId,
      rows: rowsByProductId.get(productId)
    }));
});

ko.applyBindings({ contentGrid, rowsByProduct })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<h2>By product</h2>
<ul data-bind="foreach: rowsByProduct">
  <li>
    <p data-bind="text: title"></p>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: rows">
      <li data-bind="text: id"></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```